# How do I process the output of obexpushd?

Tags: daemon, bluetooth

I am using `obexpushd` to accept files from paired bluetooth devices. I need to  extract the MAC addresses from the output of `obexpushd` to find out which file has been sent by which device.

This information is available in the only verbose option `-n` which attaches the daemon to a terminal. Now, I have two questions:

- How do I process this output directly? (grep, sed)
- If possible, how do I redirect this to a file? I tried I/O redirection and pipes, but neither work. The output keeps being sent to the terminal.

A solution **not utilising external tools** (that is, tools not present in default configuration) would be preferred. The OS is Raspbian Wheezy.

Comment: I don't have any bluetooth devices to check but it sounds like you are redirecting stdout while the program prints to stderr or vice versa.

Comment: @terdon I tested with `2>&1 1> file`, so that case should be covered.